# Fractional inequality issue

Tags: inequality

I know this is very simple for the site standard but can someone show me how to do this? I've tried ten times on my own, even looked into wolfram alpha for help but I don't get how this:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x^2 -x } -x }{ x^2 -4x +3}\leq 0$$

results in:

$\frac{1}{2}\leq x<3 , x\neq1$

Comment: is this $$\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-x}-x}{x^2-4x+3}\le 0$$?

Comment: what is your Problem now?

Comment: I need the steps in between the starting inequality and the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you must solve
$$x(2x-1)\geq 0$$ and $$x^2-4x+3\neq 0$$
from here you will get $$x\le 0$$ or $$x\geq \frac{1}{2}$$ and $$x\neq 3$$ and $$x\neq 1$$
now we have two cases:
1) $$\sqrt{2x^2-x}-x\geq 0$$ and $$x^2-4x+3\le 0$$
or2)$$\sqrt{2x^2-x}-x\le 0$$ and $$x^2-4x+3\geq 0$$
in 1) we get $$1\le x\le 3$$
in 2) we get $$x=0$$ or $$\frac{1}{2}\le x\le1$$
putting all together we get finaly $$x=0$$ or $$\frac{1}{2}\le x<1$$ or $$1<x<3$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2x^2-x}$ is defined iff $x \leqslant 0$ or $x \geqslant \frac12$.  It is obvious $x < 0$ makes the LHS positive, but $x=0$ is certainly a solution.  We restrict $x \geqslant \frac12$ for other solutions.

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-x}}{(x-3)(x-1)} \leqslant \frac{x}{(x-3)(x-1)}$$

Now $(x-3)(x-1)$ is positive when $x< 1$ or $x> 3$, and negative when $1< x< 3$. Considering when it is positive, we may cancel out and solve $2x^2-x \leqslant x^2 \iff x(x-1) \leqslant 0 \iff x \in [\frac12, 1)$ in the allowed domain.

When the denominator is negative, we may similarly solve $2x^2-x \geqslant x^2 \iff x(x-1) \geqslant 0 \iff x \in (1, 3)$

Thus we have the full solution $x \in \{0\} \cup [\frac12, 1) \cup (1, 3)$.

Comment: @Vikram Yep - didnt see that.  Sharp eyes!

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I was going about this in a more scholastic way and looking at your answer I found my mistake: I found the domain of the function at the beginning and then I forgot to use it to adjust the $x(x - 1) <= 0 <---> x { [1/2,1)$ passage, I wrongly put  $x{ [0, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) \leq 0 \qquad 
       \text{where} \qquad
       f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2x^2 - x} - x}{x^2 - 4x + 3}$$

Since $x^2 - 4x + 3 = (x-1)(x-3)$ we have to require 
$x \not \in \{\color{red} 1, \color{red} 3\}$.

Next we consider the "simpler" problem

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x^2 - x} - x}{x^2 - 4x + 3} = 0$$

\begin{align}
   \frac{\sqrt{2x^2 - x} - x}{x^2 - 4x + 3} &= 0 \\
   \sqrt{2x^2 - x} - x &= 0 \\
   2x^2 - x &= x^2 \\
   x &\in \{0, 1\} & \text{1 is an extraneous root.} \\
   x &= \color{red} 0
\end{align}

We also need to consider the subproblem $2x^2 - x \ge 0$. Again, we solve the simpler problem

\begin{align}
   2x^2 - x &= 0 \\
   x(2x-1) &= 0 \\
   x &\in \left\{\color{red} 0, \color{red}{\frac 12} \right\}
\end{align}

These points $\left\{\color{red}{0, \frac 12, 1, 3}   \right\}$ break the real number line into these intervals: 
$(-\infty, 0), 
   \left(0, \frac 12 \right),
   \left(\frac 12, 1 \right),
   (1, 3),
   (3, \infty)$

Pick any one of these intervals and let $x$ be any number in that interval. Then we must have $f(x) > 0$, $f(x) < 0$, or $f(x)$ is undefined for that particular $x$. Whichever is true will also be true for all other $x$ in that interval.
So we can make the following table.

\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
\text{Interval} & \text{Sample $x$} & f(x) 
   & \text{For all $x$ in that interval} \\
\hline
(-\infty, 0) & -4 & \frac 27 & f(x) > 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & f(0) = 0 \\
\left(0, \frac 12 \right) & \frac 14 & \text{undefined}
   & \text{$f(x)$ is undefined}\\
\frac 12 & \frac 12 & -\frac 25 & f(\frac 12) < 0 \\
\left(\frac 12, 1 \right) & \frac 34 & \approx -0.244671 & f(x) < 0\\
1 & 1 &\text{undefined} & \text{$f(1)$ is undefined} \\
(1, 3) & 2 & \approx -0.44949 & f(x) < 0\\
3 & 3 &\text{undefined} & \text{$f(3)$ is undefined} \\
(3, \infty) & 4 & 0.430501 & f(x) > 0\\
\hline
\end{array}

We end up with

$$x \in \{0\} \cup 
    \left[ \frac 12, 1 \right) \cup (1,3)$$